# Pesquisar em uma string com caracteres coringa

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função q pesquise numa string, utilizando caracteres coringa. Por Exemplo

```
linha.contains("*//*#include");
```

Answer (score 1):

No VB você tem o LikeOperator, mas no C# você precisa fazer algo customizado, a solução é criar um **[Extension Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)**

Encontrei esse exemplo [aqui](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/net/implementing-vbs-like-operator-in-c), testei e funcionou.

```
internal static class StringCompareExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implement's VB's Like operator logic.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsLike(this string s, string pattern)
    {
        // Characters matched so far
        int matched = 0;

        // Loop through pattern string
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length;)
        {
            // Check for end of string
            if (matched > s.Length)
                return false;

            // Get next pattern character
            char c = pattern[i++];
            if (c == '[') // Character list
            {
                // Test for exclude character
                bool exclude = (i < pattern.Length && pattern[i] == '!');
                if (exclude)
                    i++;
                // Build character list
                int j = pattern.IndexOf(']', i);
                if (j < 0)
                    j = s.Length;
                HashSet<char> charList = CharListToSet(pattern.Substring(i, j - i));
                i = j + 1;

                if (charList.Contains(s[matched]) == exclude)
                    return false;
                matched++;
            }
            else if (c == '?') // Any single character
            {
                matched++;
            }
            else if (c == '#') // Any single digit
            {
                if (!Char.IsDigit(s[matched]))
                    return false;
                matched++;
            }
            else if (c == '*') // Zero or more characters
            {
                if (i < pattern.Length)
                {
                    // Matches all characters until
                    // next character in pattern
                    char next = pattern[i];
                    int j = s.IndexOf(next, matched);
                    if (j < 0)
                        return false;
                    matched = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Matches all remaining characters
                    matched = s.Length;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else // Exact character
            {
                if (matched >= s.Length || c != s[matched])
                    return false;
                matched++;
            }
        }
        // Return true if all characters matched
        return (matched == s.Length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string of characters to a HashSet of characters. If the string
    /// contains character ranges, such as A-Z, all characters in the range are
    /// also added to the returned set of characters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="charList">Character list string</param>
    private static HashSet<char> CharListToSet(string charList)
    {
        HashSet<char> set = new HashSet<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < charList.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i + 1) < charList.Length && charList[i + 1] == '-')
            {
                // Character range
                char startChar = charList[i++];
                i++; // Hyphen
                char endChar = (char)0;
                if (i < charList.Length)
                    endChar = charList[i++];
                for (int j = startChar; j <= endChar; j++)
                    set.Add((char)j);
            }
            else set.Add(charList[i]);
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

Para utilizar:

```
string s = "stackoverflow123";
var ret = s.IsLike("stack*"); // true
var ret1 = s.IsLike("stack?verflow*"); // true
var ret2 = s.IsLike("*1#3"); // true
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]